# dconf reset (recovery mode)

Tags: dconf

I have messed with title bar scale set (200) and the screen is not usable anymore. So I have ability to login as recovery mode or from live usb. Can anybody help with terminal code to reset dconf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution:
just use recovery mode and use terminal (ls -a to list all folder and then cd /.config) here you can find dconf configuration folder just delete it and everything will come back normal